# Why is Google Analytics data not the same between parent page and page inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics, cross-domain

The scenario in question has a parent page in www.parent-domain.com, which contains an iframe that loads a page in www.iframe-domain.com. The parent page has Google Analytics code using TrackingID-1 and the iframe page has Google Analytics code using TrackingID-2. Each page is managed by unassociated groups, which is the reason why we are not using the same TrackingID.

When the parent page is loaded, the iframe is always loaded with it. There is no action needed by the user to load the iframe or the page inside of it. So, we expected Google Analytics data such as pageviews, users, sessions to be always the same between parent page and iframe page. Neither can be accessed from any other source, and they are both loaded simultaneously. However, the parent page pageview count is always much higher than the iframe page.

For both pages, the basic Google Analytics code is being used:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Am I missing out on some Analytics configuration setting? 
Anyone has an idea that can shed a light on this question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the free version of Google Analytics and is your data being sampled?  [Data Sampling Explained](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en)

Comment: The free and most basic version of Google Analytics given after creating an account and getting a tracking id.

Comment: Does your site receive fewer than 500k sessions per day?  If you set your date range to only look at yesterday for both properties, do the numbers match up?

Comment: Yes, even fewer than 1k sessions per day. If I set both accounts to the same date range, the numbers do not match up. The parent page always has higher numbers (pageviews, sessions, users...) than the iframe page.

Comment: Are there any filters configured for the property being tracked in the iFrame that might be excluding some visitors?

Comment: Yes, we filter out access to the iframe page from local addresses which happen during tests. Having said that, the filter is only applied in the custom dashboard. But even after adding these numbers, the parent page still has higher numbers.

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to the page that contains the iFrame?

Comment: http://www.shortsco.com.br

The 3D avatar that appears on the side is inside of a page loaded in an iframe.

Comment: Currently, Google Analytics data shows that the parent page has been viewed 77 times while the iframe page has been viewed 63.

Another test that I did was to the tracking code for the iframe page together with the parent page. In that case, it worked. The numbers became consistent.

Comment: From what I can tell by using the GA Debugger Chrome Extension, both pageview tags are firing appropriately.  I wonder if some of your user's browsers preventing analytics.js from loading.  Browser extensions such as AdBlock may also prevent an iFrame from loading external scripts, but that is just a hunch.

Comment: I was wondering if the cross domain tracking situation is applicable in this case https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

Comment: Cross-domain tracking had crossed my mind initially but I wrongfully assumed that it was unnecessary since the domains were the same.  After looking into it further, [this link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en) might describe the implementation that you are after.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I implemented the suggestion cross domain code and waited for a few hours to have enough data. Initially, it seemed to have worked but after 4h, the data started to behave like before (parent page data with higher values than the iframe page).

Comment: @BrianNorman I found out that the difference in pageviews/data occurs when Safari is used. Reading further on it, it seems to be related to Safari's default setting to block 3rd party cookies or only allow cookies from visited pages. The only viable solution I found was to include a JS in my iframe page that quickly redirects from the main page to the iframe page and then back to the main page. This way, it considers the iframe page as visited, thus allowing cookies. The data became more similar, but still has a 10% difference. Also, the redirecting is not desirable nor very adequate.
Ideas?

Comment: I agree that the JS redirect isn't ideal and will cause your bounce rate to be artificially deflated.  Perhaps you should just remove all tracking code from the iFrame page and send an artificial page view as described [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications#tracking_virtual_pageviews)